# Windows 10 - setting Java and Maven as enviroment and system variables with bash terminal

Tags: java, windows, bash, maven, environment-variables

I am working on a project on a virtual machine that is running on windows 10, and where I don't have the user access to system variables in GUI. Since, I need to use Maven I am wondering how can I set the java and maven variables with bash terminal?

I have tried to set the variable with this command:

```
 export M2_HOME="/c/Program Files/apache-maven-3.6.3" 
 export M2="$M2_HOME/bin"
 export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx512m"
```

And then if ran `mvn --version` in the terminal, I got:

> bash: mvn: command not found

If I ran `printenv` I see in the list that the variables were set:

```
M2_HOME=/c/Program Files/apache-maven-3.6.3
M2=/c/Program Files/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin
MAVEN_OPTS=-Xms256m -Xmx512m
```

But, if I close the terminal and open it again, then I don't see these variables again.
What is the right way to set up Java and Maven env variables through bash on Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the string by surrounding it with quotes:

```
export M2_HOME="/c/Program Files/apache-maven-3.6.3"
```

**EDIT:**

To answer the question in the comments, note that you still need to add `mvn`'s path to the `$PATH` variable in order to use it:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:${M2}
```

Comment: thanks for the fix, I have updated the question, because after running all the commands I was still getting that mvn is not a recognized command

Comment: thanks a lot! Do you know how can I save this, so that I don't need to set this variables every time I open the bash terminal?

Comment: @Leff You could add these `export`s to your `~/.bashrc` file.